# Woocommerce Cart Coupon Value Placeholder Change

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, placeholder

So, I thought I could change this with tried with applying

```
input#coupon_code.input-value::placeholder {
content: 'Enter Code here'; }
```

this was CSS and it didn't work, So I started to find where it was on the php's

I have a wordpress set up so i went on to `cart.php` and `coupon.php`

I'm not used to the php environment at all, so I got dizzy after looking at the % $ symbols after 30 minutes skimming all the content.

I'm currently only trying to find how to change this placeholder text, and unable to do so.

Thanks

Comment: posted anwser does it help you? hust look for the `.php` page with the `input` that have an id = `coupon_code`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets say in **coupon.php** you have the following :

```
 <p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="coupon_code" value="" />
 </p>
```

Change the `placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"`:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-first">
    <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'your placeholder text here', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" id="coupon_code" value="" />
</p>
```

Where you see **your placeholder text here** , thats where you change it.

Comment: Avoid changing templates and use the gettext filter to future proof your changes if WooCommerce is updated.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz agree

Answer (score 2):

The preferred method for changing text in WooCommerce or any plugin for that matter is to use the [gettext](https://www.speakinginbytes.com/2013/10/gettext-filter-wordpress/) filter.  It better to use a filter rather than edit the templates because templates can be changed when WooCommerce is updated.  Place the following code in your functions.php file for a more future proof solution.

```
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Coupon code' :
            $translated_text = __( 'My New Coupon Code Text', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
```